# INSERT INTO mysql issue

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to insert data into db, but there is stupid mistake which I can't see.
There should be also a connection "INNER JOIN" between users table and tilaus table. However, I don't know if I must always add the user id when I try to insert some data into tilaus table or not.

Table struct:

```
  CREATE TABLE `tilaus` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tilaaja` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
 `kuvaus` date NOT NULL,
 `tilauspvm` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `aloituspvm` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `valmistumispvm` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `hyvaksymispvm` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `tehtytyo` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `tunti` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tarvikkeet` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `kustannukset` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `tilaus_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

php code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) || (trim($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) == ''))
    {
        header('Location: login.html');
        exit;
    }
//settings
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL"); //checking connection
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>"; // connection established


$tilaaja = $_GET['tilaaja'];
$tyonkuvaus = $_GET['tyonkuvaus'];
$time = now();
$userid = $_SESSION['sess_user_id'];

echo $tilaaja; //JUST A DUMB TEST.. NOTHING TO WORRY ABOUT
echo $tyonkuvaus; // TESTING IF VAIRABLES ARE GETTING THE DATA ALREADEY OR NOT.
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tilaus`(`tilaaja`, `kuvaus`, `tilauspvm`, `user_id`) 
        VALUES ('$tilaaja','$tyonkuvaus','$time','$userid')");

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: A word to the wise: stop what you're doing *right now* and a)read up on SQL Injection and b)do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` PHP functions for new code. Look into PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: yes, every `INSERT` must have a `user_id`. This value must exist in your `users` table. Your foreign key constraint is enforcing this.

Comment: Thank you lc, I know that this code is full of security threats and rubbish. However, according to my current php course I've to do this method in my final project then with the php 2 course we will use the more secure codes..etc. So, what important now is just to get the job done with mysql and get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your field `tilauspvm` is only type `date`, you should use:

```
$time = date("Y-m-d");
```

your php code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) || (trim($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) == ''))
    {
        header('Location: login.html');
        exit;
    }

//settings
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL"); //checking connection

$tilaaja = $_GET['tilaaja'];
$tyonkuvaus = $_GET['tyonkuvaus'];
$time = date("Y-m-d");
$userid = $_SESSION['sess_user_id'];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tilaus`(`tilaaja`, `kuvaus`, `tilauspvm`, `user_id`) 
        VALUES ('$tilaaja','$tyonkuvaus','$time','$userid')");

?>
```

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);` when in development.

**mysql_*** functions is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

**Your table has:**

```
CONSTRAINT `tilaus_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
```

This means that, when adding a record in `tilaus` table, you are adding the `user_id` field. This `user_id` is a reference to the `id` field in `users` table. That means if `user_id = 5` for example, `id = 5` should exist in the `users` table.

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected that. Also, I've noticed that table kuvaus is set to date while it should be Varchar or longtext and corrected it. BTW, this is the url I'm trying to call and you can see the GET content `php/newTilaus.php?tilaaja=ssssss&tyonkuvaus=ssssss&save=Tee+uusi+tilaus` when the url opens this is the content Connected to MySQL
ssssssssssss

Comment: BTW, error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors', 1); not showing any errors

Comment: @CsharpNewbie How `user_id` is `FK` in the `users` table, check if the value in this table.

Comment: Could you please explain more? the User id is FK in tilaus table. Also, **`users`** table contains 'id' column. So the sql that I've executed was ALTER TABLE tilaus <br> ADD COLUMN user_id int, ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES users(id)

Comment: @CsharpNewbie Solved this problem?

Comment: Well,

The problem was, I didn't select db? It is annoying me so much that such stupid mistake takes too long to figure it out.

Thank you guys for your help

Comment: Yep, it is solved. Also, the user id in tilaus table is getting the correct value from id column in users table. Thank you

Comment: @CsharpNewbie if helped the solved this problem please accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

php do not have now() function it is mysql's function

so use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

or put `NOW()` directly in query

like below

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

(or)

```
VALUES ('$tilaaja','$tyonkuvaus',NOW(),'$userid')"
```

Comment: tried to use ** $time =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");**. However, not working

Comment: are you sending the data from form?

Comment: yes.Also, from the echo command I can see the data are ready to be inserted into the db.

Comment: can you post what data you are echoing?

Comment: This is the url I'm trying to call and you can see the GET content php/newTilaus.php?tilaaja=ssssss&tyonkuvaus=ssssss&save=Tee+uusi+tilaus when the url opens this is the content Connected to MySQL ssssssssssss

Comment: check by printing all these variables `$tilaaja,$tyonkuvaus,$userid`

Comment: Tried to echo all the mentioned variables plus $time and I am getting the correct results.
Connected to MySQL

test
hgggggggggg
9
2014-05-18

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mysql`, which is **deprecated** and will **not be available** in the future.

Also, Google **'MySQL injection'** and how to prevent it, since someone could hack into your database right now and alter or delete **anything**.

Try using, `echo mysql_error();` to find out exactly what is wrong.

As a bonus, you can set the `UserId` to `NULL` in your insert query and as long as a primary, auto incrementing key is set on that column, it will be created for you.

Comment: I tried to add echo mysql_error(); and it's showing nothing. Also, the userid tried to set it $userid (the actual user id that is being stored in session) and tried to use NULL without '' still not inserting anything

Answer (score 0):

In your table you have `user_id` with null as default, so the answer is "YES" you can add a record without `user_id` but you need to set NULL in the `user_id` field or just avoid mentioning it in the query.

In your code if user_id == null you put an empty string (like '') in the insert query so it should give you an error as invalid value because an empty string is different from null.